# Reducing differential equation $\frac{\operatorname d \!y}{\operatorname d \!x} = \frac{(x+y)^2 }{(x+2)(y-2)}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I'm not able to reduce the following differential equation to variable seperable form. Tried a lot. Please guide..

$$\dfrac{\operatorname d \!y}{\operatorname d \!x} = \dfrac{(x+y)^2 }{(x+2)(y-2)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set $X=x+2$ and $Y=y-2$ so the equation becomes
$$
\frac{dY}{dX}= \frac{(X+Y)^2}{XY}
$$
you can now proceed using the standard substitution $Y=VX$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, was it that easy.. :( I didn't even noticed it.

Comment: we're always learning to notice things - part of the fun!